# How to retrieve Claims Value in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, claims-based-identity, claims, asp.net-core-identity

As it says in the title I have already assigned claims to the registered user, I am now trying to retrieve the claim value when the user logs into the application within the UserClaims table in sql server which I find a bit difficult to do as this is my first time using claims.

Looking for directions on our to achieve this, thank you in advance.

```csharp
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, UserRoleId = model.RoleId };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                var callbackUrl = Url.EmailConfirmationLink(user.Id, code, Request.Scheme);
                await _emailSender.SendEmailConfirmationAsync(model.Email, callbackUrl);

                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                await addUserClaims(model.CusomterId, model.UserName);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        List<UserRole> roles = _userRoleRepo.GetAll();
        model.CreateRoleList(roles);

        List<Customer> customers = await _customerRepository.GetAll();
        model.SetupCustomerOptionList(customers);

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

        private async Task addUserClaims(string CustomerID ,string username)
    {
     
        // Customer customer = _customerRepository.GetById(customerid);
        List<Customer> customers = await _customerRepository.GetAll();
        Customer customer = _customerRepository.GetById(CustomerID);
       
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
        await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, CustomerID));
    }
```

Comment: I won't respond as answer since I don't use the built-in Identity namespace and EF stuff, but I would think you can just retrieve it from `User` as a `ClaimsPrincipal`, which means the `Claims` collection (after the user is re-authenticated, of course).

Answer (score 36):

**Set**

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
  new Claim("Currency", "PKR")
};
```

**Get**

```
@User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Currency").Value
```

Comment: A shorter version:
User.FindFirst("Currency")?.Value;

Comment: Thanks and I recommend using shorter version.

Comment: A shorter shorter version: User.FindFirstValue("Currency")

Answer (score 4):

**Very easy**

```
public static class IdentityExtension
{
    public static string GetId(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = identity as ClaimsIdentity;

        Claim claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        return claim.Value;
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
User.Identity.GetId();
```